# How to change cursor Icon in C# like in autoit

Tags: c#, cursor, autoit

I like to change the Cursor like i do in autoit with this syntax:

```
DllCall($user32, 'int', 'LoadCursorFromFile', 'str', 'data\Cursors\rotmg.cur')
```

Does someone know how to do that in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use PInvoke/DLLImport to make Windows API calls.

From [PInvoke.NET](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.loadcursorfromfile), the declaration would be:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string lpFileName);
```

And sample use:

```
IntPtr colorCursorHandle = LoadCursorFromFile("c:\\temp.cur");
Cursor myCursor = new Cursor(colorCursorHandle);
this.Cursor = myCursor;
```

PInvoke.NET is a good resource for getting the correct function signatures of PInvoke calls and structure marshalling.